# Convergence of the sum of reprocials of squares of primes.

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

I was unable to find the answer to this question online, so I figured I would ask here.

For this questions I am using the notation $p(n)$ is the nth prime.

I understand the sum

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{p(n)}$$

Is divergent.

Additionally, I know the sum
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Is convergent, and converges to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

My question is, how can I prove that the sum
$$\sum^\infty _{n=1} \frac{1}{(p(n))^2}$$
is convergent, and if so, what does it converge to?

I wrote some python code to try to find the sum it converges to, and after 10k iterations it reached 2.709 (Suspiciously close to $e$, but it seems to exceed it later)

My code can be found below:

```
import sympy as sp

i = 1
sum = 0
iterations = 10000

while i < iterations:
    r = 1/(sp.prime(i))
    sum = sum + r
    i = i + 1
    if ((i % 20) == 0):
        print(str(i) + ": " + str(sum))


print("Result after " + str(iterations) + " iterations: " + str(sum))
```

I am fully aware there are more efficient ways to do this, if you know how please let me know.

I appreciate any help, thank you for your time.

## EDIT:

My code was broken, and didn't square the denominator. The new code replaces line 9 with `r = 1/((sp.prime(i))**2)`
Following this change, it seems the sequence converges to $0.45225$.

Comment: Not all numbers are prime, so it obviously converges and is less than $\pi^2/6$: just use a comparison test with the sum you know. Regarding the numerics, see here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/53443/83537

Comment: Your code does not compute $\sum^\infty _{n=1} \frac{1}{(p(n))^2}$ but $\sum^\infty _{n=1} \frac{1}{p(n)}$.

Comment: If $a_n$ is a positive sequence with $\sum a_n$ convergent, then if $b_n$ is a subsequence, we can easily show $\sum b_n$ is convergent.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Christ, I need to up my meds. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The sum has value $$0.45224742\cdots $$

Comment: Also FYI - if a series is positive (or has at most a finite number of negatives), and there is some $M$ such that every finite sum of the series is $\le M$, then the series must converge to a limit $\le M$. In this case you have $\sum _n\frac1{p(n)^2} \le \sum_n \frac 1{n^2} \to \frac{\pi^2}6$, so that is another way to see that it converges.